# lsblk shows LVM volume as subcomponent of a partition

Tags: lvm, block-device

Given two physical drives, `sda` and `sdb`, I have:

- Used `fdisk` to make `sda1`, `sda2`, `sdb1` and `sdb2`
- Created four physical volumes accordingly: `pvcreate /dev/sda1` etc
- Created a volume group: `vgcreate datavg /dev/sda1 /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdb2`
- Created a logical volume: `lvcreate -L 4096 -n datalv datavg`
- Made a filesystem: `mkfs -t ext4 /dev/datavg/datalv`

This seems to have worked fine as far as I can tell. However, the relevant output of `lsblk` now looks like this:

```
NAME              MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                 8:0    1  58.7G  0 disk 
|-sda1              8:1    1  29.4G  0 part 
`-sda2              8:2    1  29.3G  0 part 
sdb                 8:16   1  58.7G  0 disk 
|-sdb1              8:17   1  29.4G  0 part 
| `-datavg-datalv 254:0    0     4G  0 lvm  /mnt/data
`-sdb2              8:18   1  29.3G  0 part
```

I don't quite get why `datavg-datalv` would show up *underneath* `sdb1`. Is this indicative of some error during my setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sda1` is a component device (a *physical volume* in LVM lingo) of `datavg` volume. The output of `lsblk` is perfectly normal given the command you issued.

Comment: Does that mean that the LVM showing up underneath `sdb1`, in particular, was basically just chance and it could've as well ended up under `sda2`, for example?

Comment: It means that you small 4G volume was allocated on `sdb1` only (simply because it fits in a single physical volume). Anyway, to inspect LVM you should use `pvs`, `vgs`, `lvs` and related commands. If you can/want, share the output of these commands for further inspection.

Answer (score 1):

Your LV is not large enough to span more than one PV.

Comment: That makes sense. Does that mean that the LV could've as well shown up underneath any of the other three partitions?